# instance has no attribute while passing it to instance method

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a method attribute local_filename of get_img_url to ImgurDownload but getting the error

```
"AttributeError: ImgurDownload instance has no attribute 'local_filename'"
```

Is it possible to make local_filename available in the global scope so other methods can access it?

```
import re, os, glob, sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pdb
import pprint

# imgur url pattern
imgurUrlPattern = re.compile(r'(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))(\?.*)?')


class ImgurDownload():

    #local_filename = None

    def __init__(self, link_url, target_subreddit, submissionid):
        self.link_url = link_url
        self.target_subreddit = target_subreddit
        self.submissionid = submissionid



    def download_image(self):
        response = requests.get("{}".format(self.link_url))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            #pdb.set_trace()

            #------------->2. local_filename is what i want to get from get_img_url <------------
            print('Downloading %s...' % self.local_filename)
            with open(self.local_filename, 'wb') as fo:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(4096):
                    fo.write(chunk)

    def get_img_url(self):

        if "imgur.com/" not in self.link_url:
            pass # skip non-imgur submissions

        if len(glob.glob('reddit_%s_%s_*' % (self.target_subreddit, self.submissionid))) > 0:
            pass # we've already downloaded files for this reddit submission

        if 'http://i.imgur.com/' in self.link_url:
            # The URL is a direct link to the image.
            mo = imgurUrlPattern.search(self.link_url) # using regex here instead of BeautifulSoup because we are pasing a url, not html

            imgurFilename = mo.group(2)
            if '?' in imgurFilename:
                # The regex doesn't catch a "?" at the end of the filename, so we remove it here.
                self.imgurFilename = imgurFilename[:imgurFilename.find('?')]

            #--------------------> 1. I want this instance var to be passed on to ^ download_image method <~-----------------------
            self.local_filename = 'reddit_%s_%s_album_None_imgur_%s' % (self.target_subreddit, self.submissionid, imgurFilename)
            self.download_image()

    def print_self_dict(self):
        pprint.pprint(self.__dict__)




sample = "http://i.imgur.com/yhemck6.jpg"
x = ImgurDownload('http://i.imgur.com/C5uIWlD.jpg','brogress','2cgwwn')
print x.download_image()
#x.print_self_dict()
```

Comment: As `get_img_url` calls `download_image`, you should call it instead: `x.get_img_url()` (neither function returns anything, so no need for the `print`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.local_filename` is only defined if a) you call `get_img_url` *first* and b) the link contains imgur.com. In your example, you haven't done a).

Comment: Added:x.get_img_url()
x.download_image() and now it works but wondering if there is a more efficient way of rewriting this code so it does not require two instance method calls.

Comment: @user74283 `get_img_url` *already calls* `download_image` (although I'm not sure it makes sense for it to do so...)

Answer (score 0):

When self.local_filename variable is accessed in download_image() method python will check for the local_filename instance variable. Yet because this variable was not set as an instance variable before it was accessed in download_image(), python will throw you an AttributeError.

We have assure that this variable is instantiated before accessing it. The best approach is to instantiate it inside the **init**(). Then when it comes to download_image(), it haves an initialized local_filename variable appended in to self.